# Can I format Quandl request?

Tags: python, finance, quandl

Ok, so what I need is just CVS file with basic stocks data with additional sector column for each company. Getting sectors and tickers from wikipedia works fine.

But Google/Yahoo data doesn't want to work anymore, so I've tried to use Quandl.I've recently made a few technical indicators based on it so I thought it would be great.But there is following error.

I am still in doubt if I can format my request like that so I assume that there is a problem but I can't figure a way to make it work.

Thank you for any advice and sorry for misspelings.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
import lxml
import quandl as qdl

def get_ticker_and_sector(url='https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies'):
r = requests.get(url)
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')
table = soup.find('table')

sp500 = {}

for tr in table.find_all('tr')[1:]:
    tds = tr.find_all('td')
    ticker = tds[0].text
    sector = tds[3].text
    sp500[ticker] = sector
    return sp500


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sp500 = get_ticker_and_sector()
    for i, (ticker, sector) in enumerate(sp500.items()):
        stock_df = qdl.get('WIKI/%s', start_date="2010-12-11", end_date="2011-12-31")%(ticker)
        stock_df['Name'] = ticker
        stock_df['Sector'] = sector
        if i == 0:
            all_df = stock_df
        else:
            all_df = all_df.append(stock_df)
all_df.to_csv('all_sp500_data_2.csv')
```

Error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tomek/tomek-workspace/pythons/udemy/lib/python3.5/site-packages/quandl/connection.py", line 55, in parse
    return response.json()
  File "/home/tomek/tomek-workspace/pythons/udemy/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 886, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py", line 319, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tomek/PycharmProjects/untitled4/get_file.py", line 30, in <module>
    stock_df = qdl.get('WIKI/%s', start_date="2010-12-11", end_date="2011-12-31")%('ticker')
  File "/home/tomek/tomek-workspace/pythons/udemy/lib/python3.5/site-packages/quandl/get.py", line 48, in get
    data = Dataset(dataset_args['code']).data(params=kwargs, handle_column_not_found=True)
  File "/home/tomek/tomek-workspace/pythons/udemy/lib/python3.5/site-packages/quandl/model/dataset.py", line 47, in data
    return Data.all(**updated_options)
  File "/home/tomek/tomek-workspace/pythons/udemy/lib/python3.5/site-packages/quandl/operations/list.py", line 14, in all
    r = Connection.request('get', path, **options)
  File "/home/tomek/tomek-workspace/pythons/udemy/lib/python3.5/site-packages/quandl/connection.py", line 36, in request
    return cls.execute_request(http_verb, abs_url, **options)
  File "/home/tomek/tomek-workspace/pythons/udemy/lib/python3.5/site-packages/quandl/connection.py", line 44, in execute_request
    cls.handle_api_error(response)
  File "/home/tomek/tomek-workspace/pythons/udemy/lib/python3.5/site-packages/quandl/connection.py", line 61, in handle_api_error
    error_body = cls.parse(resp)
  File "/home/tomek/tomek-workspace/pythons/udemy/lib/python3.5/site-packages/quandl/connection.py", line 57, in parse
    raise QuandlError(http_status=response.status_code, http_body=response.text)
quandl.errors.quandl_error.QuandlError: (Status 400) Something went wrong. Please try again. If you continue to have problems, please contact us at connect@quandl.com.
```

Answer (score 0):

The traceback is giving you an 400 status code which means something is wrong with the request to the API.

More specifically, Quandl's documentation says the following regarding a 400 status code:

> We could not recognize your API key. Please check your API key and try again. You can find your API key under your account settings.

As a good starting point, have you entered your API key after installing the Quandl module? [Steps are here for more information on how to do it](https://docs.quandl.com/docs/python-installation).

Please note, I only glanced at the rest of your code, and didn't test it out fully to see if there are other errors!